# Red exclamation mark over the project in eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to run a project but there is a red exclamation mark over the project name. When checked in Problems, its throwing an error "project is missing required library". The library is pointed to android.jar located in some path. When checked in package explorer, I found the android.jar in Android 2.3.1 folder structure of project in package explorer. The android.jar located in Android 2.3.1 folder is pointing to some other path. Is the build error occurring due to the difference in paths for android.jar files? I have imported the project.So, how should I modify the path which is shown in the problems window? I am newbie to android and so pls help me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to resolve this common problem is to re-associate your project with an SDK version. You do this by opening project properties, clicking on Android, select a different SDK version to that which is currently selected (if one is selected at all), click okay, and then repeat the process to switch back to the desired SDK version, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Phillip's answer and it didn't work in my case. Another place to look is opening project properties and clicking on "Java Build Path" -- if your project used some external JARs, check to make sure the links haven't been broken. If they have, reimport them again and remove the missing ones.

Answer (score 0):

Import your library through the option: ***File/ Import... / Android / Existing Android Code Into Workspace***, and not by creating a New Project and referencing the other (if you did this way).

I had this same problem and solved that way. As example, there is [a PDF](http://www.felipesilveira.com.br/android-e-facebook.pdf) which demonstrates how to import other projects [Look at the page 28] (The material are in Portuguese)